# jsPlumb multiple containment drag parent

Tags: draggable, jsplumb, containment

I have following HTML

`<div class='wraper'>
       <div class="demo statemachine-demo1">
           <div class="w" id="inperson">IN PERSON 
             <div class="ep"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="w" id="rejected">
             REJECTED
           <div class="ep"></div>
           </div>
      </div> 
      <div class="demo statemachine-demo1">
           <div class="w" id="inperson">IN PERSON 
              <div class="ep"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="w" id="rejected">
              REJECTED
              <div class="ep"></div>
           </div>
     </div> 
</div>`as per the above HTML the wrapper div contains two div each .demo div contains  two div and are connected to each other .statemachine-demo1  .inperson div to .statemachine-demo2  .inperson(.statemachine-demo1.inperson ----> .statemachine-demo2.inperson) and .statemachine-demo1  .reject to .statemachine-demo2  .reject(.statemachine-demo1.reject -----> .statemachine-demo2.reject).

now if i drag class w the join line will move continuously, but what i want to know is their any way if  i drag parent div  statemachine-demo1 the child div reject and inperson class div should also move along with joined line continuously.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need customised jquery draggable function instead of using jsPlumb.draggable() for parent div's. Whenever you drag a parent div, you need to check whether any of the child has connection, if so you need to repaint those connections. Code:

```
$('.demo').draggable({ // considering parent div has 'demo' class as in your case
        drag:function(event){
            // on drag check any child has connections and repaint them
            $(this).find('._jsPlumb_endpoint_anchor_').each(function(i,el){
                   jsPlumb.repaint($(el));
            });                 
        }
});
```